# problem with navigationController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uikit

[sorry for my weak english]

I have some method to create and show some new view controler (on top of my 
current view controler level)

```
- (void) switchToDifficultyMenu
{
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

 DifficultyMenuController *difficultyMenuController = [[DifficultyMenuController alloc] init];

   NSLog(@"navigation controller %@" , self.navigationController); //navContr is nil

 [self.navigationController pushViewController: difficultyMenuController animated: NO];

 [difficultyMenuController release];
[pool release];  


}
```

it works when i fire it for example from under tap events on my current 
view controller, but when i try to call it immediately when my current view controler 
loads (it is some need for that) id est in its -viewdidLoad the navigationController is 
nil

how can i make it work, much tnx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Until you don't push your `UIViewController` into an `UINavigationController`, the `navigationController` property will be null. The `viewDidLoad` method is always called before the push. So in the `viewDidLoad`, there is no way to access this property.

Comment: much tnx, if so then where is the place I can fire my method, as soon as possible, at the begining of previous viewcontroler creation (i want to see after my first viewcontroler on the stack, the third viewcontroler on the stack (before the second on the stack) and the second after the pop in the third :/ i know that i possibly should rebuild the 'architecture' but the first could by be more quick and easy

Comment: In this case, you should try using the `viewWillAppear:` method. The `viewDidAppear:` method will still work, but I think it doesn't have the desired effect you would like to have. I think you have 5 minutes to try out both of them and see, which corresponds your needs.