# Why is self.navigationController null in viewDidLoad?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I know there are a lot of similar questions, but I can't find one that specifically addresses this.

Why is `self.navigationController` null when called in `viewDidLoad`, but correct when called from outside `viewDidLoad`?

This is my output from `NSLog(@"%@",self.navigationController);` The first is called in `viewDidLoad`, the second I add a button to the interface with a method that calls `NSLog(@"%@",self.navigationController);`:

```
NavApp[31524:11003] (null)
NavApp[31524:11003] <UINavigationController: 0x6e21190>
```

I know there must be some simple explanation for this behavior, I'm just curious as to what it is.  Thanks!

Comment: Are you calling [super viewDidLoad] first?

Comment: There's a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7497183/problem-with-navigationcontroller. The accepted answer is the same as Mike's below, but a little less in-depth.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

A view controller's view is loaded when you first access the `-view` method/property on that controller. After the view has been loaded, the `viewDidLoad` method is called. This is pretty straight forward. You also have to remember that the view can be loaded/unloaded multiple times if memory warnings are received while the view is off-screen.

So `viewDidLoad` does not mean your view controller has been inserted into a navigation controller. In the process of pushing a view controller onto a navigation controller, its `view` will be accessed and loaded, but this will happen *before* the whole push is complete. So `viewDidLoad` is clearly getting called before the `navigationController` property has been updated.

You also have to consider that some other part of your code could be accessing the view controller's view before you even push the view controller onto the navigation controller.

So `viewDidLoad` is the wrong place to do what you are doing. You probably want to use a method like `viewDidAppear:` so you know that the view controller's view is part of the view hierarchy when it is invoked.

Comment: Yes, I moved my code to `viewWillAppear:` and it works fine. I was just curious as to the reasoning. Your post cleared it up. Thanks.

Comment: I moved my code into `viewWillAppear:` but it looks like I'm still getting some crashes. Does anyone know for certain when the `navigationController` will always not be nil?

Comment: Note that `navigationController` might still be `nil` in `viewDidAppear` if your view controller is part of a view hierarchy (e.g. attached to a `UIPageViewController`) that hasn't yet been pushed onto the navigation controller.  If you want the `navigationController` property to return an object when `viewDidAppear` is called it's up to you to make sure you've setup your view controller stack in the correct order.

Comment: Just ran into the same problem and became very frustrated. Thanks for making things clear!