# self.navigationController returns nil in ViewController pushed from a UINavigationController

Tags: ios, swift

Apologies for the wordy title

I have a `ViewController`, embedded in a `UINavigationController`. When I call `pushViewController` to a new `UIViewController`, it pushes just fine. I can set the title on the new view and everything works.

However, in that new view, `self.navigationController` does not work, it returns `nil`

### How `ViewController` is instantiated

```swift
guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
window = UIWindow(frame: windowScene.coordinateSpace.bounds)
window?.windowScene = windowScene
window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ViewController())
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

### How ViewController2 is instantiated

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    var vc2 = ViewController2()
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

But in `ViewController2`, if I `print(self.navigationController)` in ViewDidLoad, it returns `nil`. But if I do it in ViewDidAppear it works, but this is too late, as I want to set an image in the NavigationBar before the user sees it

Comment: You can always just set the image _before_ you push. It's the same navbar.

Comment: I created a new project in Xcode just now and I can't reproduce this. Are there any crucial steps, which may not seem important at first, that you forgot to mention?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10982774/6576315

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is self.navigationController null in viewDidLoad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10982567/why-is-self-navigationcontroller-null-in-viewdidload)